# Java -Modify my To String method

Tags: java, arraylist, tostring

I need to modify my toString method. The instructions are "Modify the toString method so that, first of all, it sorts the list of paychecks and then, it iterates through them to print them one at a time. We don’t want to include the [] around the elements in the ouput." I already have a sort method I wrote which I can call via PayrollUtility.sortArray(array); My current toString() method is:

```
public String toString() {

    return  String.format("\n%-27s%s\n", "Employee ID:", employeeID) +
            String.format("%-27s%s\n", "First Name:", firstName) +
            String.format("%-27s%s\n", "Last Name:", lastName) +
            String.format("%-27s%s\n", "Date of Birth:", dateOfBirth) +
            String.format("%-27s%s\n", "Date Hired:", dateHired) +
            String.format("%-27s%s\n", "Accrued Vacation Hours:", accruedVacationHours) +
            String.format("%-27s%s\n", "Amount Paid Year to Date:", PayrollUtility.convertToCurrencyStringLeftAligned(yearToDate)) +            
            String.format("%-27s%s\n", "Paychecks Received:", listOfPaychecks); 
}
```

My question is how do I remove the [] from displaying? Should I use a for loop to iterate through the list of paychecks?

Edit: I figured it out right after posting. Thank you guys for the speedy responses.

Comment: "Should I use a for loop to iterate through the list of paychecks?" Try it and see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should use a for loop to iterate through the list of paychecks and print each separately, or concatenate them into a new string.

Answer (score 0):

The alternative would be to just continue to  call the `List`'s `toString` and remove the two brackets.
That can easily be done with a `substring` call.

But manual looping gives you finer control over how you want to print each individual entry, which is maybe something you want in the future, if just to break them into multiple lines.